# Why dynamically allocated memory return different size that i actually tried to allocate?

Tags: c++, c

I want to add a string after the struct in memory.
How to check that i dynamically allocated right amount of bytes?

Example:

```
const wchar_t* add_str = L"test string";

struct test_{
    wchar_t* name;
    size_t namelen;
} test;

void* ptest_void = malloc(sizeof(test) + wcslen(add_str)*sizeof(wchar_t));
// i cant dereference void*, hence, cant check sizeof(*ptest_void)

// then i try to get sizeof of a ptr which was cast to (test_*):
test_* ptest = (test_*)ptest_void;
size_t ptest_sz = sizeof(*ptest);
// ptest_sz has the size of _test struct, but without size of add_str...
free(ptest_void);
```

Comment: `sizeof(pointer)` returns size of pointer, not the content it points to.

Comment: it was a typo, i edited the question the now there is sizeof(*ptest)

Comment: also this code supose to be C or C++? There is a difference how it should look like.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`/`free` in C++. Use `new`/`new[]`/`delete`/`delete[]` if you *must*, but in general try to avoid manual memory management entirely. Use containers first, smart pointers if you have to, raw manual memory management almost never.

Comment: i have C API (Windows ETW to be concrete), and i am in C++ project :)

Comment: What you try to do is totally misguided. Make a copy of the string, then a _fixed size_ struct, and store the copied string and the length.

Comment: As @JesperJuhl said: Use STL containers (std::vector, std::string) first. Then only if you really have to write your own datastructure prefer using std::make_unique/std_unique_ptr (or std::make_shared/std::shared_ptr if you have good enough design reasons to do so). Check it here (I don't think I needed new/delete anymore ever since C++11 came out): https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @gnasher729, yes this is how i will do it. thanks!

Comment: Not sure why so many newbies give `sizeof` this ability to dynamically query data. Some kind of wishful thinking.

Comment: `const wchar_t* add_str` change to `const wchar_t add_str[]`. Then change `wcslen(add_str)*sizeof(wchar_t)` into `sizeof add_str`.

Comment: @john I think it's because beginners are often presented with the concept of dynamically allocating arrays without clearly explaining the difference between an array and a pointer to the start of an array. Beginners will just assume that techniques that work with arrays will work with dynamically allocated arrays. They will almost never have a notion that `sizeof` is a constant expression, making the assumption seem less unreasonable.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I suggest taking a look at [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library) The term STL refers to something different from the standard library.

Comment: @john It's just a misinterpretation of what it does. It takes them a minute to realize that the type is *not* an array. It's a pretty simple mistake to make.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh duh. Oops, not my brightest momen :)

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(ptest)` doesn't tell you how much allocated memory `ptest` points to.  It tells you the size in bytes of the variable `ptest`, most likely either 4 or 8 depending on your system.

There's also no standard way to check "how big" an allocated block of memory it.  You're expected to keep track of that yourself.

If a call to `malloc` does not return `NULL`, that means the call was successful, and you can access as many bytes as you told it to allocate.